# Complex queering in the Sequelize (include, order, limit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js, psql

I have 3 models

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    static associate({ Chat, Message }) {
      this.belongsToMany(Chat, {
        through: 'UsersChats',
        foreignKey: 'userId',
        as: 'chats'
      });
      this.hasMany(Message, { as: 'messages', foreignKey: 'userId' });
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      login: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        unique: true
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
      }
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'User'
    }
  );
  return User;
};
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Chat extends Model {
    static associate({ Message, User }) {
      this.hasMany(Message, { as: 'messages', foreignKey: 'chatId' });
      this.belongsToMany(User, {
        through: 'UsersChats',
        foreignKey: 'chatId',
        as: 'users'
      });
    }
  }
  Chat.init(
    {
      name: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Chat'
    }
  );
  return Chat;
};
```

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Message extends Model {
    static associate({ Chat, User }) {
      this.belongsTo(Chat, { foreignKey: 'chatId', as: 'chat' });
      this.belongsTo(User, { foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user' });
    }
  }
  Message.init(
    {
      userId: DataTypes.UUID,
      text: DataTypes.TEXT,
      chatId: DataTypes.UUID
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: 'Message'
    }
  );
  return Message;
};
```

I'm trying to build a query like this for getting a list of chats, ordered by creation and limited by a last message

```sql
select C.name,
       C.id,
       M.text,
       M."userId"
from "Chats" as C
         left join lateral (
    select text,
           "userId",
           "createdAt"
    from "Messages" M
    where M."chatId" = C.id
    order by "createdAt" DESC
    limit 1
    ) M on true
order by M."createdAt" DESC;
```

Sequelize query

```js
Chat.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: User,
      as: 'users',
      through: {
        where: {
          id: userId
        }
      }
    },
    {
      model: Message,
      as: 'messages',
      limit: 1,
      order: [['createdAt', 'DESC']]
    }
  ],
  order: [['messages', 'createdAt', 'DESC']]
});
```

But when Execute a query, I got an exception

> SELECT "Chat"."id", "Chat"."name", "Chat"."createdAt", "Chat"."updatedAt", "users"."id" AS "users.id", "users"."login" AS "users.login", "users"."password" AS "users.password", "users"."createdAt" AS "users.createdAt", "users"."updatedAt" AS "users.updatedAt", "users->UsersChats"."createdAt" AS "users.UsersChats.createdAt", "users->UsersChats"."updatedAt" AS "users.UsersChats.updatedAt", "users->UsersChats"."chatId" AS "users.UsersChats.chatId", "users->UsersChats"."userId" AS "users.UsersChats.userId" FROM "Chats" AS "Chat" LEFT OUTER JOIN ( "UsersChats" AS "users->UsersChats" INNER JOIN "Users" AS "users" ON "users"."id" = "users->UsersChats"."userId" AND "users->UsersChats"."id" = 'a529cfbd-4104-4ed8-b135-443de9d3b41a') ON "Chat"."id" = "users->UsersChats"."chatId" ORDER BY "messages"."createdAt" DESC;
> DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: missing FROM-clause entry for table "messages"

I know, that the issue in this `order: [['messages', 'createdAt', 'DESC']]`, but I need order by last messages. What can I do, any ideas?